# Iot Hub connection string not working in azure-iot-sdk-c samples

Tags: c, azure, azure-iot-hub

I am working in a raspberry pi 3, raspbian OS, and I am using the azure-iot-sdk-c

I followed the github instructions in here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c, I downloaded and correctly built all the samples in the iothub_client/samples folder

The error is, when I put the connection string in the iothub_client_sample_http.c

Here:

```
static const char* connectionString = "[device connection string]";
```

and run it, I get many errors like this:

> Error: Time:Mon Dec 19 14:23:36 2016
>   File:/home/pi/Desktop/azure-iot-sdk-c/c-utility/adapters/httpapi_curl.c
>   Func:HTTPAPI_ExecuteRequest Line:576 Failure in HTTP communication:
>   server reply code is 401 Info: HTTP
>   Response:{"Message":"ErrorCode:IotHubUnauthorizedAccess;Unauthorized","ExceptionMessage":"Tracking
>   ID:13262df6828d469e9b29e2176a86fad3-G:9-TimeStamp:12/19/2016
>   22:23:37"} Error: Time:Mon Dec 19 14:23:36 2016
>   File:/home/pi/Desktop/azure-iot-sdk-c/iothub_client/src/iothubtransporthttp.c
>   Func:DoEvent Line:1626 unexpected HTTP status code (401)

This is my conection structure:

```
static const char* connectionString = "HostName=<myiothub>;DeviceId=<mydevice>;SharedAccessKey=<myaccesskey>";
```

Why is it giving me a 401 if I am directly using the strings provided from the azure portal?

I have tried every connection string (hubowner, service & device) and still gives me 401 :C

Comment: Is it possible the timezone and/or time are set incorrectly on your Raspberry Pi? This would cause issues with the expiry timestamp set in the SAS. I ask this because your SDK is reporting the error at 14:23:36 but the IoT Hub timestamp is 22:23:37 (UTC).

Comment: I made sure the time was correct in the raspberry, does the timezone matter as well?

Comment: Yes I believe so. This link explains how to set the timezone in raspbian: http://rohankapoor.com/2012/04/americanizing-the-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generated and used a SAS key as connection string and it all worked fine.

```
static const char* connectionString ="HostName=<myiothub>;CredentialType=SharedAccessSignature;DeviceId=<mydevice>;SharedAccessSignature=SharedAccessSignature sr=<iothub>&sig=<saskey>&se=<time>&skn=device"
```

I generated the SAS from a prebuilt version of [Device explorer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/releases)

This worked because, as explained in [Control access to IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security):

> The only way that IoT Hub authenticates a specific device is using the
>   device identity symmetric key. In cases when a shared access policy is
>   used to access device functionality, the solution must consider the
>   component issuing the security token as a trusted subcomponent.